# Why does this regular expression cause my regex engine to hang?

Tags: regex

Does anyone have any idea why this regular expression is causing my application to hang?

`/^(?:((?:.+?)(?: of the )?)+) of the (?:(.+?)) (?:"(.+?)")$/`

It hangs when I try to use it to match strings like this:

`'description of the post "This is a Post"'`

But it seems to happen pretty fast when I use it to match a shorter string like this:
`'age of the person "Bob"'`

Any ideas on why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: No, but some information about your system (language at least?) might help.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, but this problem seems to occur on any regex engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) in your regular expression, the following portion of your regex is likely the culprit:

```
((?:.+?)(?: of the )?)+
```

You should try to refactor your regular expression any time you have nested repetition.  In this case I think you can simplify that entire portion to `.+` and have your regex behave the same way.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be something like that. And you are right, that part of the regexp is the problem.

In this instance I don't think it would be a good idea to shorten that section to `(.+)` though, since I am using this in a context where there are a lot of other regular expressions checking the same string and I want to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: As long as you can avoid the nested repetition it should be okay, but I would definitely recommend using comments to avoid ambiguity instead of adding complexity to the regex.

Comment: It's not the that the regexp is ambiguous for humans, what I'm concerned about is the regexp matching something that isn't formatted the way my application expects. That's what I mean by ambiguous.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Got it, what I am saying is that the meaning of the regex does not change.  The expression `(?:.+?)(?: of the )?` will always match either any single character, or any single character followed by `of the`.  Since you repeat that expression greedily, even if `of the` can't match the `.+?` will so the entire thing is equivalent to `.+`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that. Regular expressions are tricky... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

this might be because there are so many backtracking/grouping that it takes lot of time to parse a larger string.

As you can see in the demo: http://regex101.com/r/xC3dF0, the system is not able to parse the string due to large number of backtracking

Comment: Oh, now that's a useful looking website.